# Why iteration linking works that way in Linked List

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I cannot understand fully solution of 19th problem on Leetcode.

So when we created fast and slow - we created link of head? As I can judge yes. But then we iterate with fast - why it does not change head? I mean on every step we replace fast with fast.next? So somehow it doesn’t effect head and slow.

And then we replace slow.next with slow.next.next and it does effect head.

Could you please describe how it doesn’t replace nothing on first part and replace in the second.

```
var removeNthFromEnd = function(head, n) {
    let fast = head, slow = head

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) fast = fast.next // why it doesn’t change head and slow?

    if (!fast) return head.next

    while (fast.next) fast = fast.next, slow = slow.next
    slow.next = slow.next.next // why it change head?
    return head
 };
```

Comment: Why would it affect `head` and `slow` if you're only assigning to `fast`? They're different variables.

Comment: Answer below solved it for me. I didn’t understand it correctly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning something to a *variable* will not mutate an object.

Assigning something to a *property* will mutate the object whose property you are setting.

In your case, `fast` is a variable, so assigning something to it like for example `fast.next`, will never mutate an object. It merely changes what `fast` is referencing.

On the other hand, `slow.next` is a property. Assigning something to that property will mutate the object that `slow` references.

Let's visualise what `fast = fast.next` does. Let's assume `fast` is the second node in a list of 3:

Before:

```
 head            fast 
  ↓               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: B   │   │ data: G   │   │ data: D   │
│ next: ──────> │ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

After:

```
 head                            fast 
  ↓                               ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: B   │   │ data: G   │   │ data: D   │
│ next: ──────> │ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Now look what `slow.next = slow.next.next` does. Let's assume `slow` references the first node:

Before:

```
 slow
 head
  ↓  
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: B   │   │ data: G   │   │ data: D   │
│ next: ──────> │ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

After:

```
 slow
 head
  ↓  
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: B   │   │ data: G   │   │ data: D   │
│ next: ─────┐  │ next: ──────> │ next: null│
└───────────┘│  └───────────┘┌> └───────────┘
             └───────────────┘
```

Comment: Now I see. By the wat I saw your answer for the same question, but it wasn’t fully clear for me. Now it is. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `fast = fast.next`, you are changing a reference variable. `fast` now points to the next item on the list.

When you do `slow.next = slow.next.next` you are changing a property of the object that `slow` points to.

In fact, in this example, `head` is never changed and will always point to the first element on the list.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Now it’s pretty clear for me.